# Why is there extra white space to the right of my site?

Tags: html, css

On Chrome my website displays fine, but in FF or IE, I get horizontal scrollbars and white space to the right of the site (might have to resize/refresh a couple times for it to show up).

What is causing this? My first thought was an unclosed div, but I have validated with W3C and it checks out. My other thought was something that was relatively positioned (have to do some tricky floating with a few elements.

Comment: In future, please don't ask users to visit your website and debug it for you.  Add HTML, CSS and images that illustrate your issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

here's why:

[image]

I found this by giving all elements a border of 1px, then you can use the "inspect element" to pin point it.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. This ended up being the most helpful, and I will definitely use it in future for finding things that are out of place. Thanks for going the extra distance with the screenshot.

Comment: I added borders to all elements using `* { border: 1px solid black; }`

Comment: This technique was easy and effective. I found my problem where I used 
margin-left:20px in a div and after removing it the additional whitespace vanished , Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, having a wrapper with width of 995px broke it. I changed it back to 960 and everything else seems fine. Designers designing too wide... grr. =D Thanks for looking. If anyone else knows why this was, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Looking to you page source using IE 9, it seams that the #container is forcing the browser to expand the width of your site structure:

**On your CSS, change this:**

```
#container {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 -240px 0 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**to this:**

```
#container {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Perhaps this will fix the problem for you!

Answer (score -3):

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

body {

```
min-width: 1000px;
```

}

Thanks This Made The White Frame On The Right Side GO.
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^